# EC2 Instance from custom AMI with Kubernetes cluster in it not working

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

My requirement is to have AMI with kubernetes installed so that i can launch it and start deploying app on it.
I have created EC2 instance and then installed kubernetes (1.13) on it an then created image from that. I selected NO Reboot option.
After creating image I created Ec2 instance with that AMI.
But i dont see Kubernetes running on it.

```
    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
    7719d6f0e435   3cab8e1b9802           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   6 seconds ago        Exited (1) 6 seconds ago                k8s_etcd_etcd-master_kube-system_8c95e6c43816274c9b63c52c5558161e_15
    d7f5413856be   f07fae2c3e6a           "kube-apiserver --au…"   32 seconds ago       Exited (255) 11 seconds ago             k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-master_kube-system_6d85bc2d8c1849780bb3fd5c2316c14a_13
    a83606b98160   90fd4a237264           "kube-controller-man…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_798f0580db1253017f8793d26dd60ce6_12
    7308a4bcfaf9   54f3185a42a5           "kube-scheduler --ad…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_97bd2ffa08a518ac4f55aa68c229d9f1_12
    c84e474fe245   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_798f0580db1253017f8793d26dd60ce6_12
    9125f565a433   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_97bd2ffa08a518ac4f55aa68c229d9f1_12
    9f501723ec9c   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-master_kube-system_6d85bc2d8c1849780bb3fd5c2316c14a_12
    532a568ea479   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_etcd-master_kube-syste
    48147efed229   61de39f77f45           "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   38 minutes ago       Exited (255) 2 minutes ago              k8s_ingress-controller_ingress-controller-767c485d4-qfpd8_model_701e8830-c551-11eb-9f8f-0239d268b535_11
    062a3cac464f   f59dcacceff4           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   38 minutes ago       Exited (255) 2 minutes ago              k8s_coredns_coredns-54ff9cd656-g5cmx_kube-system_a5b3c4db-c54f-11eb-9f8f-0239d268b535_11
63e1689d6e38   9c3111f27796           "/tiller"                38 minutes ago       Exited (255) 2 minutes ago              k8s_tiller_tiller-deploy-5b7c66d59c-cqcxq_kube-system_75ce666b-c550-11eb-9f8f-0239d268b535_11
68fafbc607c3   1c35c4412082           "sh -c 'chmod 777 /m…"   38 minutes ago       Exited (0) 38 minutes ago               k8s_init-server_nfs-server-d7b45f7cd-f6v9c_ao-namespace_aa8482d8-c550-11eb-9f8f-0239d268b535_0
d442713613fb   f59dcacceff4           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   38 minutes ago       Exited (255) 2 minutes ago              k8s_coredns_coredns-54ff9cd656-rtjr8_kube-system_a5b23ac8-c54f-11eb-9f8f-0239d268b535_11
68e8210a6b81   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 38 minutes ago       Exited (255) 2 minutes ago              k8s_POD_metrics-server-678f9dcb64-pbjs4_kube-system_da76bffe-c54f-11eb-9f8f-0239d268b535_69
```

UPDATE 1

I tried `docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)`
But not all container are up and see kubectl command timeout

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is to have AMI with kubernetes installed so that i can
> launch it and start deploying app on it.

Havent you considered(asking cause  dont know your full requirements) to use EKS for this purpose? Or you only limited with EC2?

This is not direct reply for your answer, closer to the 2nd option.

---

[How do I create custom Amazon Linux AMIs for Amazon EKS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-custom-linux-ami/)

To create a custom Amazon Linux AMI for Amazon EKS, you must use the following:

- [HashiCorp Packer](https://packer.io/intro/why.html) (available from the HashiCorp website)
- A build specification with resources and configuration scripts from the [Amazon EKS AMI repository on AWS GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami)
  Note: Packer works using an AWS CloudFormation stack. The stack runs an m4.large or a1.large Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance (depending on the target AMI architecture). The instance is provisioned by Packer. After the instance is provisioned with packages and binaries, Packer creates an AMI from the running instance.